# Confused keys in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, ssh

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04, and i add my ssh key to my github account, like always i did. I didn't had any problem to access to my own reports, i could clone my reports, etc... But today, maybe for any updates? (i don't know), i can't connect to github, it says: Permission denied.
For sure, i have my key added. For my surprise, if i change to another terminal (ALT + CTRL + F3 for example) and i login with the same user than the default terminal with Unity (maybe there is the problem) i can connect!!

With the default terminal (Unity) if i run this command:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

it says:

> Agent admitted failure to sign using the key. Permission denied
>   (publickey).

But if i run the same command on another terminal, it ask for my passphrase (why in the default it doesn't ask me for my passphrase?) and it's run ok with the msg:

> Hi --myname--!, You've succesfuly authenticated.....

Anyone knows what are happening?

post of ssh -vT git@github.com of default terminal:

```
> OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012 debug1: Reading
> configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
> line 19: Applying options for * debug1: Connecting to github.com
> [204.232.175.90] port 22. debug1: Connection established. debug1:
> identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa type 1 debug1: Checking
> blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048 debug1: Checking
> blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048 debug1: identity file
> /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
> /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 debug1: identity file
> /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
> /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 debug1: identity file
> /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1: Remote protocol
> version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1
> Debian-6+squeeze1+github12 debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1
> Debian-6+squeeze1+github12 pat OpenSSH_5* debug1: Enabling
> compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr
> hmac-md5 none debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent debug1:
> expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
> sent debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY debug1: Server host
> key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48 debug1: Host
> 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key. debug1: Found key
> in /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts:4 debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature
> correct debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting
> SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1: Roaming not
> allowed by server debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent debug1:
> SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received debug1: Authentications that can
> continue: publickey debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
> debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa debug1:
> Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279 Agent admitted failure to
> sign using the key. debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa debug1: Trying private key:
> /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa debug1: No more authentication methods to
> try. Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Why in default terminal it doesn't ask for my passphrase and in another terminal it's asking me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears something may be amiss with your keys and authentication agent.  In your Unity terminal session, try:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0 ssh -vT github
```

One clue is that you're using a different authentication agent if you're running in an X session versus a text (vty) console.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign